# Ubuntu releases .iso torrent SHA wrong

Tags: xubuntu, iso, bittorrent, checksums

I have downloaded ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso  and ubuntu-16.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso using a torrent client transmission.

ubuntu-16.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso was downloaded from the ubuntu downloads page and ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso was dl from a popular torrent site.

After dl i checked both sha256 again what is in thefollowing link and both sha's were different
http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/16.04/release/SHA256SUMS

here is what i got

```
sha256sum ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso 
dc7dee086faabc9553d5ff8ff1b490a7f85c379f49de20c076f11fb6ac7c0f34  ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso
```

it should `be204c08075e8537000b4d38009fe3cad1210816269e314879918368312c74bce8`

and the other

```
sha256sum ubuntu-16.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso 
6b505fd3b6f816f8ff058710f127a9900e9233e496783ce08a0022814d224810  ubuntu-16.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso
```

it should be

```
8d11f07fce7b5cc85e2d6211394eb63569b88c76b95f8d72cc6eb859dbe45ee9
```

Any ideas? I would of thought the 16.04.5 release dl from the ubuntu site would of been correct, I could understand the other being incorrect as someone may have modified it before putting it on the torrent site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are wrong.

- your download is for Ubuntu.
- your hashes you link to are for xUbuntu.

Link to Ubuntu: http://releases.ubuntu.com/xenial/SHA256SUMS for 16.04.5 says

```
6b505fd3b6f816f8ff058710f127a9900e9233e496783ce08a0022814d224810 *ubuntu-16.04.5-  desktop-amd64.iso
```

Comment: Thank you, Any idea where i can find the sha for 16.04.1 i can not find it and this is the version i need as i run into issue with 16.04.5. the link you provided only has the shas of 16.04.5 versions

Comment: 16.04.1 has gone end of life so on  the "archives" website. http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/16.04.1/